# Karate - Compare multiple JSON objects schema

Tags: java, testing, automation, karate

I am trying to validate a JSON which has multiple JSON objects nested.
example

```
  Scenario: temp1
* def response1 =
"""
{
"productGroups": [
    {
        "dateLabel": "28 Aug, Wed",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1439,
                "product": "product 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 1401,
                "product": "product 2"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
"""
* print response1.productGroups
Then match response1.productGroups[*] contains
"""
{
  'dateLabel': #string,
  'products': [
    {
      'id': #number,
      'product': #string
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

Getting the response as

> reason: actual value does not contain expected

if I change the validate as

```
Then match response1.productGroups[0] contains
```

Getting the response as

> reason: actual and expected arrays are not the same size - 2:1

What I wanted to do is verify the schema of "productGroups" object along with the inner objects of "products"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please spend some time reading the docs, it is worth it: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation

```
* def product = { 'id': #number, 'product': #string }
Then match response1.productGroups[*] contains
"""
{
  'dateLabel': #string,
  'products': '#[] product'
}
"""
```